# Can ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers work with descendant classes?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

If a partial view is based upon a base class, is it possible to check if it is a descendant class and if so, use the descndant class' properties within the Html helpers (LabelFor, EditorFor etc.)?

```
@model ProjectX.Models.VehicleModel

<div>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fuel)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fuel)
</div>

@{
    if (Model is CarModel)
    {
        CarModel car = (CarModel)Model;

        @Html.LabelFor(car => car.Doors)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(car => car.Doors)
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean check if the Model is a descendant, rather than the View, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible; try this ...

**Model classes**

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Vehicle
    {
        public string Fuel { get; set; }
    }

    public class Car : Vehicle
    {
        public int Doors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication2.Models.Vehicle

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>


<div>
     @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fuel)
     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fuel)
</div>

@{
    if (Model is MvcApplication2.Models.Car)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => ((MvcApplication2.Models.Car)model).Doors)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => ((MvcApplication2.Models.Car)model).Doors)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is whether you can use descendants of Models with @Html, then I see no reason why not. The code you provide should work.

Comment: It doesn't work as it is a lambda and therefore 'car' is the name given to the parent 'Model' class object.